# ¿Cómo hacer esta expresión regular?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Necesito meter en un input de tipo texto un patrón que cumpla las siguientes condiciones.

- Que contenga " - ". Con espacios incluídos.
- Que antes del " - " haya una palabra.
- Que la siguiente palabra al " - ", acabe en 'r'
- Que pueda incluir caracteres especiales como 'ñ' o tildes.

Un ejemplo válido sería el siguiente: Tarea uno - Planificar reunión

Hace mucho que no toco las expresiones regulares y no me acuerdo de ciertas cosas, y me estoy volviendo un poco loco.

**EDITO**

He estado haciendo varios intentos a raíz del siguiente patrón:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([ - ])*([r])*[a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

No lo debo de estar poniendo bien, porque cuando quito el guión me lo sigue dando como bueno.

Estoy progando en regexr, y el resultado que me da es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con la respuesta que me ha dado @Marcos, el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: deberias agregar el texto de entrada lo que as intentado y el resultado esperado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías usar la siguiente expresión regular:

```
/[a-zÀ-Ü]+ - [a-zÀ-Ü]+r/i
```

Donde:

1. `[a-zÀ-Ü]+`: al menos un caracter de la `a` a la `z` y de `À` a `Ü` ([caracteres acentuados](https://www.ascii-code.com/) desde `192 al 220`)
2. `-`: seguido de espacio, guión, espacio
3. `[a-zÀ-Ü]+r`: item punto `1`, pero termianda en `r`
4. `i`: bandera que indica `case insensitive` (*insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas*)

#### Demo:

```js
const regEx = /[a-zÀ-Ü]+ - [a-zÀ-Ü]+r/i;

document.getElementById('texto').addEventListener('input', function() {
  console.log(this.value, regEx.test(this.value));
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto" />
```

**Nota:**

Si quisieras limitar los caracteres acentuados, simplemente podrías listarlos, por ejemplo, `[a-záéíóúñ]`

Comment: Este tiene buena pinta, pero está limitado a solo una palabra, necesitaría que no hubiera límite de palabras

Comment: Con la que me has comentado y la frase "Tarea uno - Planificar reunión", me da por bueno el apartado "uno - Planificar". Edito la pregunta principal para que puedas verlo.

Comment: Vale no, disculpame, lo estaba enfocando mal... Es exactamente eso, tienes razón. Muchísimas gracias! :D